# Cookies function not saving the Data

Tags: php

This code is intended to just take an ID and Pass without any kind of authentication and remember the data if the checkbox were to be checked. I can not figure it why is it not saving the data to cookies.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["chk"],$_POST["id"],$_POST["pass"])) {

   $id=$_POST["id"];
   $pwd=$_POST["pass"];

     if (isset($_POST["chkbx"])){

      setcookie("id","$id",time()+3600);        
      setcookie("pwd","$pwd",time()+3600);
         $id=$_COOKIE["id"];
         $pwd=$_COOKIE["pwd"];
  }
  print "Your ID " . $id;
  print "Your PASS ". $pwd;
  }
  ?>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>
        Remember Me
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    Please Enter ID and PASS
    <form method="post" >
       Enter ID
        <input type="text" name="id" />
       Enter PASS
        <input type="text" name="pass" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" /><br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx" />Remember Me
   <input type="hidden" name="chk" value="true" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you expecting `$_COOKIE["id"]` to work right after `setcookie`, it doesn't work like that. you haven't sent any response. `setcookie` defines cookies to be sent in the response headers

Comment: @swadhwa I took it out from that if clause but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is correct but it needs to clean it up

in this part I add a condition to check is there is anything first in the `$_COOKIE`
before print it

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['id']) && isset($_COOKIE['pwd'])){
    print "Your ID: " . $_COOKIE['id'] . '<br>';
    print "Your PASS: ". $_COOKIE['pwd'] . '<br>';
}
```

your code will be like this

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $pwd = $_POST["pass"];

    if (isset($_POST["chkbx"])){
        setcookie("id", $id ,time()+3600);        
        setcookie("pwd", $pwd, time()+3600);
    }
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['id']) && isset($_COOKIE['pwd'])){
    print "Your ID: " . $_COOKIE['id'] . '<br>';
    print "Your PASS: ". $_COOKIE['pwd'] . '<br>';
}
?>


<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Remember Me
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    Please Enter ID and PASS
    <form method="post" >
       Enter ID
        <input type="text" name="id" value="<?= isset($_COOKIE['id'])? $_COOKIE['id']: '' ?>" />
       Enter PASS
        <input type="text" name="pass" value="<?= isset($_COOKIE['pwd'])? $_COOKIE['pwd']: '' ?>" />
   <input type="submit" value="submit" /><br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx" />Remember Me
   <input type="hidden" name="chk" value="true" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes. I can see it now.my code is working too. yours is more cleaner and not beginner-like. but can you tell me how do I keep the ID and PASS input pre filled the next time user visits?

Comment: @lovecoding i update the answer you could check it again

Comment: That is PERFECT. Thank you for your time and help. I will Learn from this..

Comment: you are welcome, please if the answer helped you vote it up

Comment: it says i can't upvote until i'm at 15. currently i'm at 12. i will once i'm at 15. thanks again man!